# Automatically fill out songs meta data on OS X

Tags: macos, itunes, metadata

Sometimes when I get .mp3s they are missing some of their meta data (album, genre, year released, lyrics, album art) and iTunes does not fill it in for me (apart from album art, somtimes).

What 3rd party applications out there will scan through my library and fill out all the missing meta data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [IEatBrainz](http://wiki.musicbrainz.org/IEatBrainz).  It uses the MusicBrainz system to automatically tag your files.  The UI isn't quite as polished as you might expect for a mac app, but it works pretty well.  It doesn't change the iTunes metadata, so you will have to update that separately.  Fortunately, it is fairly easy: Just find the file in iTunes and hit Command-I to get file info.  iTunes will read the tags and update its metadata.

Comment: This doesn't work on leopard (at least for me) and MPFreaker doesn't work well on some songs...

Comment: All I can offer is: "It works for me."  If you want to get it going, you could open a new quesiton on the topic.

Answer (score 1):

There is [MusicBrainz](http://musicbrainz.org/) and there used to be iEatBrainz for the Mac that used MusicBrainz but I don't think it is being maintained.

Comment: It may not be maintained, but it still worked fine when I used it to retag all my music a couple of months ago :-)

Answer (score 0):

MusicBrainz Picard works just fine on OS X. http://musicbrainz.org/doc/PicardDownload